# Автоперенос элемента QComboBox

Tags: pyqt5, qcombobox, wordwrap

Столкнулся с проблемой автопереноса элементов выпадающего списка `QComboBox`, то есть, если элемент не помещается в ширину списка, он будет выводиться вот так:

```
очень дли...элемент
```

Я хочу реализовать, чтобы значение элемента выводилось полностью и строка автоматически переносилась в случае нехватки места, а результат получался таким:

```
очень длинный 
элемент
```

Я делал похожее с `QTableWidget`, и там работал метод `resizeRowsToContents()`, но в `QComboBox` это не работает.

Возможно ли это реализовать в `QComboBox`?

Пример:

```
combo1 = QComboBox(self)
combo1.setGeometry(100, 270, 350, 50)
combo1.addItem("ооооченьььь длинннннннннннннннный элемееееееент")
```

[image: Результат]

Мне надо избавиться от точек посередине, чтобы элемент выводился полностью, а те символы, которые не помещаются, переносились на следующую строку.

*Python 3.6.2* 
*PyQt5 5.15.4*

Comment: использовать QStyledItemDelegate

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev, спасибо, буду копать в этом направлении

Comment: @S.Nick, дополнил вопрос примером

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я предложу вам попробовать другой возможный вариант (не совсем автоперенос), 
отличный от того что вам уже предложили.

Есть две внешне похожие строки. 
Посмотрите как они выглядят после применения:

[**sizeAdjustPolicy:SizeAdjustPolicy**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#sizeAdjustPolicy-prop)  определяет, как подсказка размера `QComboBox` должна регулироваться
при добавлении нового содержимого или изменении содержимого.

[**sizePolicy:QSizePolicy**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop)
содержит поведение `layout` по умолчанию для виджета.

```
    self.combo.SizeAdjustPolicy(QComboBox.AdjustToContents)
    self.combo.setSizePolicy(                              
        QSizePolicy.Maximum,                               
        QSizePolicy.Minimum                               
    )
```

А также посмотрите как это все выглядит в различных
стилях, которые доступны на вашем ПК.

Класс **`QStyleFactory`** создает объекты `QStyle`.

Класс `QStyle` - это абстрактный базовый класс, который инкапсулирует
внешний вид графического интерфейса пользователя. 
`QStyleFactory` создает объект `QStyle`, используя функцию `create()`
и `key`, определяющий стиль. 
Стили либо встроены, либо динамически загружаются из подключаемого модуля стиля
(см. [QStylePlugin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleplugin.html)).

Действительные `keys` можно получить с помощью функции `keys()`. 
Обычно они включают "**`windows`**" и "**`fusion`**". 
В зависимости от платформы могут быть доступны "**`windowsvista`**" и "**`macintosh`**".
Обратите внимание, что ключи нечувствительны к регистру.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.combo = QComboBox()
        self.combo.setObjectName('comboBox')
        self.combo.setMinimumContentsLength(22)                               # !!!
        
        self.combo.addItem(
            "ооооченьььь длинннннн \n1234567890 нннннннннный \nэлемееееееент")
        self.combo.addItem(   #    ^^<----                   ^^<----          # !!!
            "ооооченьььь длинннннн 1234567890 нннннннннный элемееееееент")

        # Добавить стили из QStyleFactory
        self.combo.addItems(QStyleFactory.keys())
        # Выберите текущий стиль интерфейса
        index = self.combo.findText(
            'Fusion',
            Qt.MatchFixedString
        )
        
        self.combo.SizeAdjustPolicy(QComboBox.AdjustToContents)               # !!!
        self.combo.setSizePolicy(                                             # !!!
            QSizePolicy.Maximum,                                              # !!!
            QSizePolicy.Minimum                                               # !!!
        )

        self.btn = QPushButton("Это кнопка.")
        self.btn.setFixedSize(78, 78)
        
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)        
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        
        self.combo.currentTextChanged.connect(self.onActivated)        
        self.combo.setCurrentIndex(index)
        
    def onActivated(self, value):
        QApplication.setStyle(value)                                      # !!!
        self.btn.setFocus()

qssStyle = '''
QComboBox {
    color: #91091E;
    background: #BDC7C9;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
QComboBox:hover {
    background-color: rgb(236, 236, 136);
}
QComboBox#comboBox::drop-down { 
/*    image: none;           */
    image: url(monkey.png); 
}
'''    
 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qssStyle) 
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(100, 100)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**monkey.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: большое спасибо, что уделили время моему вопросу. Однако я столкнулся с проблемой. Когда я подгружаю стиль, то этот стиль добавляется как элемент QComboBox. Я попытался скрыть его вот так:

        `view = self.combo.view()`

        `view.setRowHidden(2, True) `

Однако при запуске этот элемент все равно виден. Возможно ли как то решить данную проблему?

Comment: @AndreyM, я не знаю как вы подгружаете стиль, но если вы хотите сменить стиль, который применяется по умолчанию - добавьте строку `app.setStyle('Fusion')` после строки `app = QApplication(sys.argv)` и все.

Comment: да вот теперь работает, спасибо. Единственное, у меня программа многооконная, и желательно бы стиль применить, лишь к одному окну, впрочем, это уже другой вопрос, ответ на который я попытаюсь найти самостоятельно.

Comment: да, конечно, уже сделал. Еще раз спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @AndreyM, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вам понадобится [QListView](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QListView.html) (с небольшими, но важными настройками), [QStringListModel](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QStringListModel.html) (это для примера, можно и любую другую модель) и сам [QComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QComboBox.html).

Пример:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidget import QComboBox, QListView, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QStringListModel

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    combo = QComboBox()
    combo.setMaximumWidth(150)

    # Данные заполняются через модель QStringListModel
    combo.setModel(QStringListModel([
        '1. Lo',
        '2. Lorem',
        '3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur',
        '4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut',
        '5. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco labor'
    ]))

    # Отображатель выпадающего списка QListView
    listView = QListView()
    # Включаем перенос строк
    listView.setWordWrap(True)
    # Устанавливаем отображатель списка (popup)
    combo.setView(listView)
    combo.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Спасибо, тоже очень интересный вариант, возьму на карандаш

Comment: @AndreyM пожалуйста, пользуйтесь на здоровье! )